# pcre_regex with conditional patterns, "or" and "and" conditions

Tags: regex, pcre

Am using a [pcre-regex-engine](http://pcre.org/) to match pattern from my file/line. The lines am trying to find a match are:

```
line-001 key_one:10.20.30.40 any data goes here
line-002 key_two:11.22.33.44 any data goes here
line-003 key_off:12.32.42.52 any data goes here
line-004 key_ten:34.45.67.89 any data goes here
```

Now, I want to match ip patterns starting with `key_one:`,`key_two:` or`key_ten:`. I need my pattern to be conditional,"match any ip pattern starting with `key_one:`or,`key_two:` or `key_ten:`.

expected pattern= `key_one | key_two| key_ten & (\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)`

But, The or(|) condition works for pcre,but not the and(&) condition. can some one help me out to use the and (&) condition? thank u.

Comment: What was the actual pattern you tried?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank u for your replay. i tried this: ((key_one | key_two| key_ten) (\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)), but it gives me an output like: key_one:10.20.30.40 , key_two:11.22.33.44, but i want the ip-string only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is almost correct: you did not consider that the spaces in the pattern are meaningful (in PCRE, outside the character classes) unless `/x` modifier is used, and that there is a colon between the values. Also, a dot must be escaped to match a literal dot.

You may use

```
(key_(?:one|two|ten)):(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
```

that is a contracted form of

```
(key_one|key_two|key_ten):(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G6pVeH/1)

If you need to get the IP as a match value, use `\K` operator to discard all the text matched up to that operator and return only what is matched later:

```
key_(?:one|two|ten):\K\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/G6pVeH/3).

Note that it is best practice to write the alternatives in such a way that none of them could match at the same location (to improve performance), that is why it is not a good idea to repeat the same `key_` substring within the `(...|...)`.

The `+` quantifier matches 1 or more occurrences and in IP addresses there can only be one to three digits, that is why a limiting quantifier `{1,3}` seems more reliable.

Also, to avoid unnecessary captures, just turn *capturing* (`(...)`) groups into *non-capturing* ones (`(?:...)`).

Comment: But, does the engine(pcre) support the "and" condition, just like the "or" one? i want to check that way, like....match this,or this and this.

Comment: That is what groupings are for. Match `a1` or `b2` and then `c3` => [`(a1|b2)c3`](https://regex101.com/r/hB9Xo6/1). The `&` condition that you expect here, is just a sequence of obligatory (=matching at least 1 occurrence) subpatterns.

Comment: Regarding *but i want the ip-string only* - you have them in Group 2. Capturing groups are meant to be used when you need to access a submatch (part of a match). Alternatively, use either a lookbehind: [`(?<=key_one:|key_two:|key_ten:)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}`](https://regex101.com/r/G6pVeH/2) or `\K`: [`key_(?:one|two|ten):\K\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}`](https://regex101.com/r/G6pVeH/3).

Comment: @kahsaykalayu: You should be more clear what you mean by `&`. If you mean you want to make sure there is `a1` and  then `b2` and there can be any text between them, you can use [`/a1.*b2/s`](https://regex101.com/r/NIWT6G/1). If you want to check if a string has `a1` and `b2` *regardless* of their order in the string, you may use [`/^(?=.*a1)(?=.*b2).*/s`](https://regex101.com/r/NIWT6G/2). So, there is no some miraculous `&` operator in PCRE, all depends on each concrete case/scenario. Only ElasticSearch regex supports *Intersection* in regex with `&`.

Comment: Perfect as expected, The \K option (lookbehind) did the trick.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133068/discussion-between-kahsay-kalayu-and-wiktor-stribizew).